# Matplotlib axes resizing to accommodate text

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have been attempting to use matplotlib to generate a bar graph like this

[image: 1]

However, note that the number above the black bar exceeds the top axis line. I have tried using `ax.relim()`, `ax.autoscale()`, `ax.autoscale_view()`, to correct this problem, but without success.

My question is: is there a way to cleanly get the axis size to account for the size of the text displayed by ax.text, without manually computing the height of the text+rectangle and manually resizing appropriately?

I am using Python 2.7.3 and Matplotlib 1.3.x

EDIT:

Manually resizing the window using the text size information obtained from some renderer hacks  solves this problem. The code is given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categoryList = ['F', 'L', 'M', 'T', 'W']
categoryColors = {'C': 'y', 'B': 'r', 'F': 'g', 'M': 'b', 'L': 'm', 'T': 'c', 'W': 'k'}
categoryNames = {'C': 'foo1', 'B': 'foo2', 'F': 'foo3', 'M': 'foo4', 'L': 'foo5', 'T': 'foo6', 'W': 'foo7'}
timeList = [60, 165, 60, 10, 570]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
width = 0.35

legendColors = []
legendNames = []
texts = [] 
for ind in range(len(categoryList)):
    category = categoryList[ind]
    rects = ax.bar([ind],timeList[ind],width,color=categoryColors[category],align="center")
    legendColors.append(rects[0])
    legendNames.append(categoryNames[category])

    # Add the text for the number on top of the bar
    for rect in rects:
        texts.append(ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2,1.05*rect.get_height(),'%d' % timeList[ind],
                    ha='center',va='bottom'))
# The x axis indices
ind = range(0,len(categoryList))

ax.set_ylabel("Time (Minutes)")
ax.set_xlabel("Category")
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(categoryList)
lgd = ax.legend(legendColors,legendNames,bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.3)

# Epic hacks for getting renderer
fig.savefig('foo.png',bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,),bbox_inches='tight')
renderer = fig.axes[0].get_renderer_cache()

window_bbox_list = [t.get_window_extent(renderer) for t in texts]
data_bbox_list = [window_bbox.transformed(ax.transData.inverted()) for window_bbox in window_bbox_list]
data_coords_list = [data_bbox.extents for data_bbox in data_bbox_list]
height_list = [coordEntry[-1] for coordEntry in data_coords_list]
max_height = max(height_list)
fig.axes[0].set_ylim(top=max_height*1.05)
fig.savefig('foo.png',bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,),bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: `fig.axes[0].get_renderer_cache()` has been deprecated since matplotlib 3.6, the respective line must now read `renderer = ax.figure.canvas.get_renderer()`, but everything else still works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I really don't think there is a clean and automatic way, as text is an object that has a live that is almost independent from the axes where you draw it. In fact, it doesn't have an actual dimension until you draw the whole figure...

The method is to keep track of all the text that you add in the plot, for example doing:

```
texts = []
for your_element in your_cycle:
    do something
    t = ax.text(your_text_params)
    texts.append(t)
```

then you need to find the highest reached point of your text. To do this you have to extract the window coordinate information and transform them into data coordinate. Before you can do this you have to draw your figure, otherwise the text is yet to be determined (if someone knows better, please correct me).

```
plt.draw()
window_bbox = [t.get_window_extent()  for t in texts]
data_bbox =   [ b.transformed(ax.transData.inverted()) for b in window_bbox ]
data_coords = [ b.extents for b in data_bbox ]
```

after obtaining the coordate extents, we extract the maximium of each boxes and the maximum among them, then set the border to a little more than that

```
max_height = [ e[-1] for e in data_coords ]
top = max(max_height)
ax.set_ylim(ymax=top*1.05)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This worked, with a little rendering hack to get around the `draw()` requirement so that I could use `figure.savefig()`. See my edit for the full code.